# Insert record into Junction object

Tags: apex, junction-object

How to insert record into junction object. I have a junction object for contract and order, junction object (Contract_Order__c). When I try to insert a record into junction object I am getting an error that `Attempt to de-reference a null object`. I checked my debug log the junction object have value in it before adding it to Contract_Order__c list. But even then I am getting error. IS there any other way to do it. Or I am not doing it in a proper way. Please guide me to get the solution. 
Mu code:

```
if(createConatract.size() > 0){
        for(Contract c : createConatract){
            Contract_Order__c co = new Contract_Order__c(co.Contract__c = c.Id, co.Order__c = orderID, co.CurrencyIsoCode = 'USD');             
            system.debug('Value in contract order before adding to list ' + co);
            contractOrder_InsertLst.add(co);
        }
    }

    //Inserting Contract Order
    if(contractOrder_InsertLst.size() > 0)
        insert contractOrder_InsertLst;
```

Comment: I don't see any obvious errors, can you maybe add the rest of your code as well? It's likely something like the list (contractOrder_InsertLst) not existing if your system.debug() line works as expected.

Comment: To be clear, when you say "even then" you're getting the error, do you mean it's showing null in the log or it's printing correctly?

Comment: Is this being executed from a before insert trigger by any chance?

Comment: contractOrder_InsertLst= new Contract_Order__c[] {} or another init of this array before other code :)

Comment: If the error is happening on `insert contractOrder_InsertLst;` then it could be an issue with other code. Can you include the full stacktrace you are getting?